# Some browsers (Explorer / Firefox) don't recognize UTF-8 special character

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, utf-8

I'm using an script to show text from a database and this works just fine in Chrome but not in Explorer and Firefox. The problem lies probably in the special characters (UTF 8).
I.e. The name-selection Peter works fine in IE/FF and shows peter-infomation but Désiree is not showing any Désiree-information (but it exist and Chromes shows it) and this is probably caused by the special é-character.
Hereby the HTML-heading and script-code and hopefully someone can provide me the right solution?

```
<head>    
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/ola.css'  />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/ola_table.css' />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
</head>

--+--

<script>
function showUser(str, strKlas, strPer)
{
//alert("Binnen: " + str + " - Klas: " + strKlas + " - Periode: " + strPer);
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?klas="+strKlas+"&periode="+strPer+"&q="+str,true);
//xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?klas=4B1&periode=1&q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to IE11, Internet Explorer would not automatically URLEncode characters in the URL parameter passed to the `open` method of the XmlHttpRequest object.

You should use the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aeh9cef7%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method to encode the URL explicitly.

So:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?klas=" + encodeURIComponent(strKlas) + 
    "&periode="  +encodeURIComponent(strPer) + 
    "&q="+encodeURIComponent(str), true);
```